# C++ Sha return different value every time

Tags: c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
std::stringstream ss;

    std::string data;
    data = "hello worl";
    unsigned char digest[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    char *string1 = strdup(data.c_str());


    SHA1((unsigned char*)&string1, strlen(string1), (unsigned char*)&digest);    

    char mdString[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH*2+1];

    for(int i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
         sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);

ss.str("");
ss << mdString;

 cout << ss.str() << std::endl;

    // do stuff with string1
    free(string1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
user1@ubuntu:~/yes/coding$ g++ -o sha sha.cpp -lcrypto
user1@ubuntu:~/yes/coding$ ./sha
1bc8b06c5cd4e774195293ea00c959173d8d3789
user1@ubuntu:~/yes/coding$ ./sha
c8cf70c522fc564aedb5894a24613542702172ca
user1@ubuntu:~/yes/coding$ ./sha
83fbda098c3549ab1347d6cf708ac85092200423
user1@ubuntu:~/yes/coding$ ./sha
ea6ccffd78236e22da412ed90a852329f59f8fd5
user1@ubuntu:~/yes/coding$ ./sha
0413799befebcb23f5a5c970e48febc7f1aa27fb
user1@ubuntu:~/yes/coding$ ./sha
7bd8e7952c78e282b8c117f8c537c456b66207d9
```

Comment: Quick question: what happens if you turn on warnings (`-Wall`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SHA1((unsigned char*)&string1, ...)
```

Drop the ampersand. You are not hashing the text you want to hash; you are hashing four bytes that form the address of the first character of the string, plus six bytes of random garbage that sit above `string1` on the stack.